# Keep only the final or the latest rev of a file name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with columns as below:

```
  Name                                                         Measurement
0 Blue_Water_Final_Rev_0                                             3
1 Blue_Water_Final_Rev_1                                             4
2 Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2                                             5
3 Red_Water_Final_Rev_0                                              7
4 Red_Water_Initial_Rev_0                                            6
```

I want to keep only the rows with the latest rev or rows with "Final" if the other is "Initial".
In the case above, my output will be as below:

```
 Name                                                         Measurement
2 Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2                                             5
3 Red_Water_Final_Rev_0                                              7
```

How can I do this in python in my pandas dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: Is possible row with only `Initial` and not `Final` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the name before "Final" and `drop_duplicates` with `keep='last'`:

```
keep = (df['Name']
        .str.extract('^(.*)_Final', expand=False)
        .drop_duplicates(keep='last')
        .dropna()
        )

out = df.loc[keep.index]
```

*NB. Assuming the data is sorted by revision.*

Output:

```
                     Name  Measurement
2  Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2            5
3   Red_Water_Final_Rev_0            7
```

If you want to keep all duplicates of the last revision:

```
out = df[df['Name'].isin(df.loc[keep.index, 'Name'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible exist only `Initial` and no `Final` and need keep it use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get 3 columns for groups, `Final` or `Initial` and number of revision, convert last column to integers and then sorting by all columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and get last duplicates per groups by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
print (df)
                        Name  Measurement
0     Blue_Water_Final_Rev_0            3
1     Blue_Water_Final_Rev_1            4
2     Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2            5
3      Red_Water_Final_Rev_0            7
4    Red_Water_Initial_Rev_0            6
5  Green_Water_Initial_Rev_0            6

df1 = (df['Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<a>\w+)_(?P<b>Final|Initial)_Rev_(?P<c>\d+)$')
                 .assign(c=lambda x: x.c.astype(int)))

df = df[~df1.sort_values(['a','c','b'], ascending=[True, True, False])
            .duplicated('a', keep='last')]
print (df)
                        Name  Measurement
2     Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2            5
3      Red_Water_Final_Rev_0            7
5  Green_Water_Initial_Rev_0            6
```

But if need remove all `Initial` and processing only `Final` rows use first part same like above, only then filter out rows with `Initial` and for last revisions use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df1 = (df['Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<a>\w+)_(?P<b>Final|Initial)_Rev_(?P<c>\d+)$')
                 .assign(c=lambda x: x.c.astype(int)))

df = df.loc[df1[df1.b.ne('Initial')].groupby('a')['c'].idxmax()]

print (df)
                     Name  Measurement
2  Blue_Water_Final_Rev_2            5
3   Red_Water_Final_Rev_0            7
```

Comment: When I follow your steps it gives the error: Cannot convert float NaN to integer. I have no NaN in my 'Name' column. Also see my comments to mozway. I want to keep all instances of the latest rev and not remove duplicates of the latest revision. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can you the df.iloc[2:4,:] for this

Comment: Hi @Tharindu Kavinda This will not solve the problem as I have millions of rows of data. The table I gave was only an example and not the actual thing.